# Cannot change the target CPU to x86 Or x64 in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, asp.net-2.0, cpu, target

I am trying to build a website application and specify the target CPU as x86 instead of Any CPU. The only choices I have in Configuration Manager under the "Active solution platform:" drop-down list are: "Any CPU", "Edit..", and "New...".

In the "Project Contexts" portion of the "Configuration Manager" window, it lists 3 columns: "Project", "Configuration" and "Platform".  Under the "Platform" column, my only choice is ".Net". when the "Active solution configuration" is set to, "Debug".

When the, "Active solution configuration" is set to "Release", then I can choose either, ".Net" or "Any CPU" under the "Platform" column.

I am using Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition.  This website was previously built using Visual Studio .NET and was recently upgraded using the Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition Upgrade Wizard.

I need to target x86 specifically because the are components used in the project that are only x86 compatible.

Comment: My previous answer was for WinForms and Class libraries; for websites, you don't see the x64/x86 options.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sooo... in other words, I'm looking for an option that isn't available for websites? Well, it appears my understanding of developing websites with Visual Studio is not nearly as complete as I had thought. :) I appreciate the time and effort you put in to trying to help me R.M.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net code is run in the CLR( Common Language Runtime). It never compiles to a native x86-compatible binary, it compiles to a CIL(Common Intermediate Language) byte-code file, which gets run in the CLR.

CLR is an execution environment that is comparable to the Java Virtual Machine. Compiles once, and then it doesn't matter what kind of CPU you're running it on, as long as the platform has a Common Language Infrastructure interpreter (The Mono project is an open-source CLI interpreter, the CLR is Microsoft's CLI interpreter).

Answer (score 0):

If you select the "" option in that box, you may notice that it gives you the x86 and x64 options when the new prompt box pops up and offers selections. I know it does on mine.

I know this is about 2 years later than the question and 1 year later than the last answer, but I figured it should be posted for others that may run into it anyway.